# How to make a Play and Pause Button for Stopwatch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement play and pause function in my code. But after pausing once it's not starting again. I tried to store the update timer function in a object then calling it outside from the class so that I can pause it. How can I improve my implementation?

```js
var playPause = document.querySelector(".playpause");
var x = document.querySelector(".div");
var y = document.querySelector(".div1");
var countdown = document.querySelector(".countdown");
const initialTime = 20;
let time = 0;
let lala = 1;
let gate = false;

const timerClass = {
  updatecountDown: setInterval(function() {
    const min = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let sec = time % 60;
    sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
    countdown.innerHTML = `${min}:${sec}`;
    let ini = (time * 100) / initialTime;
    let percentage = ini * (1 / 100) * y.offsetWidth;
    x.style.width = percentage + "px";
    if (time == initialTime) clearInterval(updatecountDown);
    time++;
  }, 1000),
};
timerClass.updatecountDown;

playPause.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  if (gate == false) {
    clearInterval(timerClass.updatecountDown);
    playPause.innerHTML = `Play`;
    gate = true;
  } else {
    // Want to write something here so that timer start again
    timerClass.updatecountDown;
    playPause.innerHTML = `Pause`;
    gate = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.div {
  background: orange;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: gray;
}

.dot {
  background-color: hotpink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.countdown {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <pc class='countdown'>10.10</pc>
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div">
      <span class="dot">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="playpause">Pause</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want `updatecountDown` to be a function. Currently, it is a property that holds the timer id (returned by `setInterval`).

I would suggest creating two functions start and stop like so

```
const timerClass = {
  // holds the timer Id
  updatecountDown: null,
  // start/resume timer
  start: function() {
    this.updatecountDown = setInterval(function() {
      const min = Math.floor(time / 60);
      let sec = time % 60;
      sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
      countdown.innerHTML = `${min}:${sec}`;
      let ini = (time * 100) / initialTime;
      let percentage = ini * (1 / 100) * y.offsetWidth;
      x.style.width = percentage + "px";
      if (time == initialTime) this.stop();
      time++;
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  },
  // pause timer
  stop: function() {
    clearInterval(this.updatecountDown);
  }
};

// Starting timer
timerClass.start();
// timerClass.updatecountDown;

// changing from mouseup to click
playPause.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  if (gate == false) {
    // clearInterval(timerClass.updatecountDown);
    timerClass.stop();
    playPause.innerHTML = `Play`;
    gate = true;
  } else {
    // Want to write something here so that timer start again
    // timerClass.updatecountDown;
    timerClass.start();
    playPause.innerHTML = `Pause`;
    gate = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to pull out the function passed into `setInterval`. By doing that you can call it directly when you need to restart it. The issue is that once you clear the interval, `timerClass.updatecountDown` is null and has no concept of the interval function.

```js
var playPause = document.querySelector(".playpause");
var x = document.querySelector(".div");
var y = document.querySelector(".div1");
var countdown = document.querySelector(".countdown");
const initialTime = 20;
let time = 0;
let lala = 1;
let gate = false;

const intervalFn = function() {
  const min = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let sec = time % 60;
  sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
  countdown.innerHTML = `${min}:${sec}`;
  let ini = (time * 100) / initialTime;
  let percentage = ini * (1 / 100) * y.offsetWidth;
  x.style.width = percentage + "px";
  if (time == initialTime) clearInterval(timerClass.updatecountDown);
  time++;
};

const timerClass = {
  updatecountDown: setInterval(intervalFn, 1000),
};

playPause.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  if (gate == false) {
    clearInterval(timerClass.updatecountDown);
    playPause.innerHTML = `Play`;
    gate = true;
  } else {
    // Want to write something here so that timer start again
    timerClass.updatecountDown = setInterval(intervalFn, 1000);
    playPause.innerHTML = `Pause`;
    gate = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.div {
  background: orange;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: gray;
}

.dot {
  background-color: hotpink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.countdown {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <pc class='countdown'>10.10</pc>
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div">
      <span class="dot">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="playpause">Pause</button>
</body>
```